# Что означают сокращения pos и neg, от каких слов сокращения (конкретно neg)?

Tags: 3d, терминология

Есть вот такая кубическая карта (развертка) с обозначениями. Что они значат?

Pos - от "position" (или нет?)
neg   от какого слова?

Прямого отношения к работе не имеет, просто хочется знать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос желательно детализировать, т.к. по картинкам поиск плохо работает.

Answer (score 4):

Pos - Positive - Положительное направление (знак плюс по оси)
Neg - Negative - Отрицательное направление (знак минус по оси)

Конкретно по кубическим картам, это направление в котором каждая сторона куба расположена по осям X Y Z.

P.S. Конкретные направления во многом условны. В зависимости от движка/API оси координат могут быть заданы в разных направлениях и ориентациях (правая/левая система координат), так что, например, однозначного "Z всегда смотрит вверх" нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]